# PostGIS throwing error during installation via PostgreSQL Installer

Tags: postgresql, macos, postgis

I am new to PostgreSQL and am following a Real Python tutorial to do some geocoding and mapping. The first part of the tutorial is to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS databases. The first time I tried this through the PostgreSQL installer it froze, the second time I tried it returned the error in the screenshot below. When I try to run the suggested sudo command in terminal it returns `command not found`. I have tried to uninstall PostgreSQL twice now and delete associated folders but it is still presenting the same error when I try to install PostGIS.

Hoping someone may know how to help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.

Use Homebrew to install postgis with `brew install postgis` this worked.